# В терминале VSC'а работают команды "npm", но не распознаются команды "ng", подскажите пожалуйста, что мне делать, спасибо!)

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs, visual-studio-code

```
PS C:\Users\Ismailovs\Documents\Проект обучения\angular-basics> ng generate component post2
```

> ng : Имя "ng" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность нап
> исания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.

```
строка:1 знак:1
+ ng generate component post2
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А как насчет `npx ng generate component`? Вообще это не от терминала зависит, просто CLI-команды пакета не зарегистрированы (это происходит только при глобальной установке, да и то не всегда). Утилита `npx` - умеет резолвить локально установленные пакеты.

Comment: @yar85 всё сработало, большое спасибо!)))
P.S я новичок просто)